# Terminal and unity launcher is missing

Tags: command-line, unity, python, launcher

My python script containing `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` was not working and one of my classmate suggested to remove one of the python packages. (My dell ubuntu 12.04 desktop has two python programme 2.7 and 3) So, I run the command `sudo apt-get remove python`. Now my terminal and unity launcher is missing. How can I recover everything without reinstalling? I can login in the `tty` .

Thank you in advance.

(P.S. I understand removing python was a bad idea)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Python? I don't know if that will fix it, just asking.

Comment: Oh wait, you're running 12.04. You need to upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: please suggest a way without up gradation because sometimes it stuck.

Comment: [Backups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) are very helpful to have at times like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reinstall Terminal and Unity.

You also need to install Python again.

Login to `tty` and type this command:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop gnome-terminal && sudo apt-get install python` (or whatever is it's name)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Unity and Gnome-Terminal depend on Python, but I can't check at the moment.

Comment: result after the above comand "E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem." Please suggest a way to fix this problem.

Comment: Result after running 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' followed by 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop gnome-terminal && sudo apt-get install python' "E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)"

Comment: @Heisenberg Try "sudo apt-get -f" to fix your problem.